# IDA Pro Symbian Debugger 'general OS related' Error

Tags: disassembly, debuggers, assembly, ida, visual-basic

I am using remote symbian: c5-03 (Application TRK 3.2.7 for all S60 5.0 devices with production images). However, whenever I start the debugger, I get this error:

```
general OS-related error
```

[image]

What went wrong? How do I solve the issue?

Comment: You do have "root" rights to execute a debugger?

Comment: Contact support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a software application or configuration. It should be posted on the relevant software support site.